# Lock-free multi-producer multi-consumer queue

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, lock-free, producer-consumer

I'm looking for some feedback on my lock-free queue, based on Disruptor, mainly for any potential concurrency issues, such as where I need additional fences. It looks correct to me, and I can't seem to able to break it, but I'm only testing it on my x86 machine.

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T> class LockFreeMPMCQueue
{
    public:
    explicit LockFreeMPMCQueue( size_t size )
        : m_data( new T[size] ), m_size( size ), m_head_1( 0 ), m_head_2( 0 ), m_tail_1( 0 ), m_tail_2( 0 )
    {
    }

    virtual ~LockFreeMPMCQueue() { delete[] m_data; }

    // non-copyable
    LockFreeMPMCQueue( const LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>& ) = delete;
    LockFreeMPMCQueue( const LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>&& ) = delete;
    LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>& operator=( const LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>& ) = delete;
    LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>& operator=( const LockFreeMPMCQueue<T>&& ) = delete;

    bool try_enqueue( const T& value )
    {
        const std::uint64_t head = m_head_2.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );
        std::uint64_t tail = m_tail_1.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );

        const std::uint64_t count = tail - head;

        // count could be greater than size if between the reading of head, and the reading of tail, both head
        // and tail have been advanced
        if( count >= m_size )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if( !std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(
            &m_tail_1, &tail, tail + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        m_data[tail % m_size] = value;

        while( m_tail_2.load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) != tail )
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }

        // Release - read/write before can't be reordered with writes after
        // Make sure the write of the value to m_data is
        // not reordered past the write to m_tail_2
        std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_release );
        m_tail_2.store( tail + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );

        return true;
    }

    bool try_dequeue( T& out )
    {
        const std::uint64_t tail = m_tail_2.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );
        std::uint64_t head = m_head_1.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );

        if( head >= tail )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if( !std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(
            &m_head_1, &head, head + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        out = m_data[head % m_size];

        while( m_head_2.load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) != head )
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }

        // Release - read/write before can't be reordered with writes after
        // Make sure the read of value from m_data is
        // not reordered past the write to m_head_2
        std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_release );
        m_head_2.store( head + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );

        return true;
    }

    size_t capacity() const { return m_size; }

    private:
    T* m_data;
    size_t m_size;

    // Make sure each index is on its own cache line
    char pad1[56];
    std::atomic<std::uint64_t> m_head_1;
    char pad2[56];
    std::atomic<std::uint64_t> m_head_2;
    char pad3[56];
    std::atomic<std::uint64_t> m_tail_1;
    char pad4[56];
    std::atomic<std::uint64_t> m_tail_2;
};
```

Comment: For those less familiar with lock-free synchronization, what are the reasons behind the padding for each of the atomic counters?

Comment: @glampert It's to make sure the indexes are on separate cache lines, I'm making the assumption that a cache line is 64 bytes, which it is for most current x86 processors (I actually got the padding size wrong originally, I've amended that). If an index is written to on thread A, if the index is cached in thread B then it will be updated, this comes at the cost of time. Without the padding, all the indexes are likely on the same cache line, so a write to any of them results in the updating of the other threads caches. More info here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Missing barrier

When I looked at your code, I could immediately tell there was something wrong because you use a release barrier without an acquire barrier that pairs with it.

You have this barrier in `try_enqueue()` between writing to `m_data` and writing to `m_tail_2`:

> ```
> std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_release );
> ```

But you don't have any corresponding acquire barrier in `try_dequeue()` between reading from `m_tail_2` and reading from `m_data`.  You should put in a barrier like this:

```
bool try_dequeue( T& out )
{
    // ...

    // Add this barrier which pairs with the other release barrier
    std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_acquire );

    out = m_data[head % m_size];

    // ...
}
```

Without this barrier, the cpu could read `m_data[head]` speculatively before the read of `m_tail_2`, and you could end up getting an older value instead of the value just written.

#### Sequence of events that lead to error

1. Initially, `m_data[0] = 0`
2. Cpu 1: `try_enqueue()`: `m_data[0] = 5`
3. Cpu 1: `try_enqueue()`: `fence(release)`
4. Cpu 1: `try_enqueue()`: `m_tail_2 = 1`
5. Cpu 2: `try_dequeue()`: reads `m_tail_2` as `1`
6. Cpu 2: `try_dequeue()`: `exchange(head, head+1)` (no effect)
7. Cpu 2: `try_dequeue()`: reads `m_data[0]` as `0`

Due to weak memory ordering, on step 7 above, `m_data[0]` can be read as `0` instead of `5` because there was no acquire barrier between steps 5 and 7.  The strong exchange on step 6 did not perform a barrier because it was called with `std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed` as the memory ordering.

Note that there are 2 possible ways that memory accesses can be "reordered".  The first is that the compiler might shift lines of code around, and therefore, your accesses are *actually* performed out of order with respect to a program execution timeline.  This is not what is happening in my example above.  The second way is that the memory system may reorder accesses.  In other words, even if two reads occur one after the other in the program execution timeline, the second read may read an earlier value than the first read.  This second case is what causes step 7 above to fail.

#### Possible missing barrier

Similarly, you might need an acquire barrier in `try_enqueue()` before your write to `m_data`, which pairs with the release barrier in `try_dequeue()`.  I say "might" because this one is harder to explain.  The barrier is only needed if the cpu would do a speculative write to `m_data` before reading `m_head_2`.  But because `m_head_2` is used to determine whether or not to actually write to `m_data`, there is a data dependency there which would seem to guarantee that `m_head_2` is read before writing to `m_data`.  However, there are processors such as the DEC Alpha which have strange behavior with respect to data dependencies.  So I'm not 100% sure about whether this barrier is needed, and if it *is* needed, it may only be needed for DEC Alpha and similar processors.

Comment: `atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit` might change the value of `head`, so I was under the impression that the read of `m_data[head]` couldn't be reordered before the `atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit`. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Joe - you are right. None of these fences are required on x86. cmpxchg acts as a fence.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae but would they be required on PPC/Arm/Dec Alpha?

Comment: @Joe I added a section to explain the sequence of events that would lead to an error.

Comment: @JS1 thanks for clarifying, makes sense now!

Comment: @Joe, I don't really know about weak-ordered platforms. I don't even know a single person who worked low level on them. I'm more interested to know how did my username become a guid!

Comment: @JS1 just to add to your explanation of the shortcomings in `try_dequeue`, I was re-reading [Jeff Preshing's post about memory barriers](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) and he talked about how stores can be re-ordered on their way from L1->L2->RAM, and reads can be re-ordered from RAM->L2->L1. So just because I've got an updated value of `m_tail_2` with which the decision is made to do the compare-and-swap, doesn't actually mean that `m_data` is up to date as well.

Comment: @JS1 could you pls review this code ? [naive lock-free work stealing queue](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158711/naive-lock-free-work-stealing-queue), thank you. :)