# Naive lock free work stealing queue

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, lock-free

Recently, I read a article about work stealing queue  [Job System 2.0: Lock-Free Work Stealing – Part 3: Going lock-free](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2015/09/25/job-system-2-0-lock-free-work-stealing-part-3-going-lock-free/), and this is my c++11 naive implementation based on my understand of c++11 memory order model. This works on x86 , as x86 has a strong memory model, is there any issue running on other architecture (weak memory order)?

```
#include <atomic>

class Job;

struct WorkStealingQueue
{
    // only called by owner work thread
    void Push(Job* job) noexcept
    {
        // m_bottom -> stealing thread read, owner thread read, write.
        auto bottom = m_bottom.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        m_jobs[bottom & MASK] = job;

        // need  let stealing thread see the new job.
        m_bottom.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    // only called by owner worker thread 
    Job* Pop(void) noexcept
    {
        auto bottom = m_bottom.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        auto top = m_top.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (bottom > top)
        {
            auto job = m_jobs[(bottom - 1) & MASK];

            if(top < (bottom - 1)) 
            {
                m_bottom.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
                return job;   
            }
            if (m_top.compare_exchange_weak(
                top, top + 1,
                std::memory_order_release,
                std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                return job;
            } 
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    // called by stealing thread, not owner thread
    Job* Steal(void) noexcept
    {
        auto top = m_top.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        // Release-Acquire ordering, so the stealing thread see new job
        auto bottom = m_bottom.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (bottom > top)
        {
            auto job = m_jobs[top & MASK];
            // check if other stealing thread stealing this work 
            // or owner thread pop this job.
            // no data should do sync, so use relaxed oreder
            if (m_top.compare_exchange_weak(
                top, top + 1,
                std::memory_order_release,
                std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                return job;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:

    static constexpr auto MAX_COUNT = 4096u;
    static constexpr auto MASK = MAX_COUNT - 1u;
    static_assert((MAX_COUNT & MASK) == 0, "the max number of job must be power of two.");

    Job* m_jobs[MAX_COUNT];
    std::atomic<unsigned int> m_bottom{ 0 }, m_top{ 0 };
};
```

Comment: "is this implementation correct" Did you check it? On Code Review, only working code is allowed. Please check the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast this code works on my x86-64 PC， lock-free may has issue on other arch platform. So I am looking for expert help.

Comment: Question: is there only one thread pushing and one thread popping (i.e. single producer, single consumer)?  Or are there multiple producers / consumers?

Comment: @JS1  Pop(), Push() performed on the same one thread, Steal() performed on the others multiple threads.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast got that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Pop() has problem

Consider what happens if your queue is in the following state with two jobs:

```
m_top    = 0
m_bottom = 2
```

The owner thread calls `pop()`, and loads in to local variables:

```
top    = 0
bottom = 2
```

Now, before the owner thread does anything else, two stealer threads call `steal()`, leaving the state of the queue like this:

```
m_top    = 2
m_bottom = 2
```

When the owner thread continues inside of `pop()`, it will go into this case and return a job that no longer exists:

> ```
>     if(top < (bottom - 1)) 
>     {
>         m_bottom.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
>         return job;   
>     }
> ```

Your code deviated from the code you linked.  In the linked code, the first thing that `pop()` did was to decrement `m_bottom` so that the stealer threads could not steal the bottom job.

Comment: thank you, i will rewrite `Pop()` follow that article.

Comment: hi, i rewrote `Pop`, please help to review it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any issue running on other architecture (weak memory order)?

Well, `std::atomic` isn't guaranteed by the standard to be *lock free*. It totally depends on the target CPU's architecture, and capabilities.

If there are single operations supported by the CPU to access and change specific values, they will be *lock free*. Otherwise any operations on `std::atomic` may need to use an implementation that involve a synchronization mechanism (semaphore or mutex).

For reference you can read

- [`std::atomic_is_lock_free, ATOMIC_xxx_LOCK_FREE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free) how to determine that at compile time

and

- [Are atomic variables lock-free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106936/are-atomic-variables-lock-free)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite `Pop()` followed by reference article.

```
#include <atomic>

class Job;

struct WorkStealingQueue
{
    // only called by owner work thread
    void Push(Job* job) noexcept
    {
        // m_bottom -> stealing thread read, owner thread read, write.
        auto bottom = m_bottom.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        m_jobs[bottom & MASK] = job;

        // need  let stealing thread see the new job.
        m_bottom.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    // only called by owner worker thread 
    Job* Pop(void) noexcept
    {
        auto bottom = m_bottom.fetch_sub(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        auto top = m_top.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (bottom >= top)
        {
            auto job = m_jobs[bottom  & MASK];

            if(top != bottom) 
            {
                return job;
            }
            auto top1 = top + 1;
            if (!m_top.compare_exchange_weak(
                top, top1,
                std::memory_order_release,
                std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                job = nullptr;
            } 
            m_bottom.store(top1);
            return job;
        }
        m_bottom.store(top, std::memory_order_release);
        return nullptr;
    }

    // called by stealing thread, not owner thread
    Job* Steal(void) noexcept
    {
        auto top = m_top.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        // Release-Acquire ordering, so the stealing thread see new job
        auto bottom = m_bottom.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (bottom > top)
        {
            auto job = m_jobs[top & MASK];
            // check if other stealing thread stealing this work 
            // or owner thread pop this job.
            // no data should do sync, so use relaxed oreder
            if (m_top.compare_exchange_weak(
                top, top + 1,
                std::memory_order_release,
                std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                return job;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:

    static constexpr auto MAX_COUNT = 4096u;
    static constexpr auto MASK = MAX_COUNT - 1u;
    static_assert((MAX_COUNT & MASK) == 0, "the max number of job must be power of two.");

    Job* m_jobs[MAX_COUNT];
    std::atomic<unsigned int> m_bottom{ 0 }, m_top{ 0 };
};
```

Comment: By the original algorithm: in Push(), fetch_add isn't needed, as store(bottom + 1, memory_order_release) is sufficient. In Pop(), the original article insists on a CPU fence between storing bottom and loading top. fetch_sub(1, memory_order_relaxed) has the wrong memory order; it should be memory_order_seq_cst (on x86(-64), the interlocked add happens to be a fence, but this is broken on other memory models). Also, fetch_sub() isn't necessary; exchange(bottom + 1, memory_order_seq_cst) works.

Comment: Display Name is right. Also the load from bottom in Steal should be seq_cst, as well as the compare_exchange on top. Some of the stores to bottom can also be relaxed, as well as some of the loads from top. You should use something like relacy (https://github.com/dvyukov/relacy) to verify your lock free C++ code.